# Joining results of two queries: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: sql, join, alias

I'm trying to combine the results produced by two queries on my database...

q1:

```
SELECT * FROM werkgevers JOIN werkgevers_branches ON werkgevers.werkgever_id = werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id JOIN plaatsen ON werkgevers.plaats_id = plaatsen.plaats_id JOIN branches ON werkgevers_branches.branche_id = branches.branche_id GROUP BY werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id
```

q2:

```
SELECT werkgever_id, COUNT(werkgever_id) AS aantalvacatures FROM vacatures GROUP BY werkgever_id
```

... like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM werkgevers JOIN werkgevers_branches ON werkgevers.werkgever_id = werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id JOIN plaatsen ON werkgevers.plaats_id = plaatsen.plaats_id JOIN branches ON werkgevers_branches.branche_id = branches.branche_id GROUP BY werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id
) AS tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT werkgever_id, COUNT(werkgever_id) AS aantalvacatures FROM vacatures GROUP BY werkgever_id
    ) AS tbl2
)
USING (werkgever_id)
```

but I keep getting the error

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

I'm not sure where I should name any derived tables, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your LEFT OUTER JOIN derived table needs an alias. Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from werkgevers
    join werkgevers_branches on werkgevers.werkgever_id = werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id
    join plaatsen on werkgevers.plaats_id = plaatsen.plaats_id
    join branches on werkgevers_branches.branche_id = branches.branche_id
    group by werkgevers_branches.werkgever_id
    ) as tbl1
left outer join (
    select *
    from (
        select werkgever_id,
            COUNT(werkgever_id) as aantalvacatures
        from vacatures
        group by werkgever_id
        ) as tbl2
    ) a USING (werkgever_id)
```

Note the alias `a` on the last line.

Comment: This query is wrong. COUNT(werkgever_id) and group by werkgever_id ?? oO

Comment: @aF It's not necessarily wrong, although I would not write it that way.

Comment: you're being to literal ^^ this is a very wrong way to put 1 in aantalvacatures column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Both queries separately give me exactly what I need, the suggestion from RedFilter gets rid of the alias problem, but now I've got a #1060 - Duplicate column name 'werkgever_id'. I'll try to figure out where that's coming from :)

Comment: @user1435406 If you stop using `*` and name the columns explicitly, you won't have that problem.

Comment: I've just found that out, I had multiple werkgever_id columns from the first query. Thanks anyway! (Select * is evil, I know ^^)